# Configure volumes in airflow GKEStartPodOperator operator

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have a google cloud composer environment. In my DAG I want to create a pod in GKE. When I come to deploy a simple app based on a docker container that doesn't need any volume configuration or secrets, everything works fine, for example:

```
kubernetes_max = GKEStartPodOperator(
    # The ID specified for the task.
    task_id="python-simple-app",
    # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
    name="python-demo-app",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    location=CLUSTER_REGION,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
    # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
    cmds=["python", "app.py"],
    namespace="production",
    image="gcr.io/path/to/lab-python-job:latest",
)
```

But when I have an application that need to access to my GKE cluster volumes, I need to configure volumes in my pod. The issue is the documentation is not clear regarding this. The only example that I ever [foud](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html) is this:

```
volume = k8s.V1Volume(
    name='test-volume',
    persistent_volume_claim=k8s.V1PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource(claim_name='test-volume'),
)
```

While the volumes in the my manifest file (I use it to deploy my app from local) looks like this:

```
volumes:
  - name: volume-prod
    secret:
      secretName: volume-prod
      items:
        - key: config
          path: config.json
        - key: another_config
          path: another_config.conf
        - key: random-ca
          path: random-ca.pem
```

So when I compare how both volumes looks like in the console (when I manually deploy the manifest file that successfully run, and when I deploy the pod using clod composer that fails):

- The successful run - Manifest file:

  volume-prod
  Name: volume-prod
  Type: secret
  Source volume identifier: volume-prod
- The failed run - Composer `GKEStartPodOperator`:

  volume-prod
  Name: volume-prod
  Type: emptyDir
  Source volume identifier: Node's default medium

How I can configure my pod from cloud composer in a way it can read the volume of my cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KubernetesPodOperator`/`GKEStartOperator` is just a wrapper around the python Kubernetes sdk - I agree that it isn't well documented in the Airflow/Cloud Composer documentation but the Python SDK for Kubernetes itself is well documented.

Start here with the kubernetes python sdk documentation: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodSpec.md

You'll notice that the arguments the `KubernetesPodOperator`/`GKEStartOperator` take match this spec. If you dig into the source code of the operators you'll see that the operator is nothing more than a builder that creates a `kubernetes.client.models.V1Pod` object and uses the API to deploy the pod.

The [operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_api/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod/index.html#airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod.KubernetesPodOperator) takes a `volumes` parameter which should be of type `List[V1Volume]`, where the documentation for `V1Volume` is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Volume.md).

So in your case you would need to provide:

```py
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

kubernetes_max = GKEStartPodOperator(
    # The ID specified for the task.
    task_id="python-simple-app",
    # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
    name="python-demo-app",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    location=CLUSTER_REGION,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
    # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
    cmds=["python", "app.py"],
    namespace="production",
    image="gcr.io/path/to/lab-python-job:latest",
    volumes=[
        k8s.V1Volume(
            name="volume-prod",
            secret=k8s.V1SecretVolumeSource(
                secret_name="volume-prod",
                items=[
                    k8s.V1KeyToPath(key="config", path="config.json"),
                    k8s.V1KeyToPath(key="another_config", path="another_config.conf"),
                    k8s.V1KeyToPath(key="random-ca", path="random-ca.pem"),
                ],
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

Alternatively, you can provide your manifest to the `pod_template_file` argument in `GKEStartPodOperator` - this will need to be available to the workers inside airflow.

There are 3 ways to create pods in Airflow using this Operator:

1. Use the arguments of the operator to specify what you need and have the operator build the `V1Pod` for you.
2. Provide a manifest by passing in `pod_template_file` argument.
3. Use the Kubernetes sdk to create a `V1Pod` object yourself and pass this to the `full_pod_spec` argument.